# @ExceptionHandler local vs global

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I am going to introduce the **global handler** on my web application:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(CustomRuntimeException.class)
    public @ResponseBody ImmutableMap<?, String> handleNullResponseException(CustomRuntimeException e) {
        return ImmutableMap.of(e.getClass(), e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

But the issue is that legacy code contains **a few controllers with local handlers** like this:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public @ResponseBody ExceptionDetails handleException(Exception e) {
    return handleException(e);
}
```

And when controller throws **CustomRuntimeException** **it handles by local one not global**. In order to fix it I can add to each of these controllers local handlers similar to global. But as for me it is not a good one.

**The question**: Is it possible to redirect handling custom exceptions to the global handler?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put more specific Exceptions in Local `ExceptionHandler` and more general Exceptions in Global `ExceptionHandler`. Similar to Java Exception handling. If you put the General one in Local, all Exceptions will end up there because it is the closest one and accepts any exception.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
@ExceptionHandler(IOException.class)
public @ResponseBody ExceptionDetails handleIOException(IOException e) {
    return handleException(e);
}

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
@ExceptionHandler(NullPointerException.class)
public @ResponseBody ExceptionDetails handleNPException(NullPointerException e) {
    return handleException(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring exceptionHandler works kind of like the try and catch

When the controller has an exception and it has a local exception handler the request will be handled by the local exception handler. Now if it does not find local then we tries to look for global.

In your case local exceptionHandler handles all exception thus global exception handler not called.